# Наполнение словаря значениями другого словаря в python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

У меня не получается какая-то тривиальная задача по наполнению данными словаря в Python 3.
Для понимания исходных данных в списке spisok1 вот его нулевой элемент
spisok1[0] =

```html
<offer id="122" available="true">
        <url>http://tornado-spb.ru/catalog1/otpugivateli/otpugivateli_sobak/_/?utm_medium=cpc&amp;utm_source=yamarket&amp;utm_campaign=122</url>
        <enable_auto_discounts>true</enable_auto_discounts>
        <price>1590</price>
        <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
        <categoryId>568</categoryId>
        <country_of_origin>Россия</country_of_origin>
        <vendor>Тайфун</vendor>
        <vendorCode>468267002</vendorCode>
        <model>ЛС-300+</model>
        <picture>http://tornado-spb.ru/images/cms/data/98c0bf06b2a5ad098215094e4d26e03a.jpeg</picture>
        <delivery>true</delivery>
        <name>Электронный отпугиватель собак «Тайфун» ЛС-300+</name>
        <description>Одна из самых первых моделей электронного отпугивателя собак с максимальной дальностью до 30 метров. Работает от батарейки "Крона". Проверено временем!</description>
        <sales_notes>При доставке в дальний регион нужна предоплата</sales_notes>
        <manufacturer_warranty>true</manufacturer_warranty>
        <param name="Источник питания">Крона</param>
        <param name="Максимальная дальность действия">30 м</param>
        <param name="Диапазон излучаемых частот">18...25 кГц</param>
        <param name="Уровень ультразвукового давления на расстоянии 1м">не менее 130 дБ</param>
        <param name="Габариты">90x50x25 мм</param>
        <param name="Масса без батареи">0,08 кг</param>
        <param name="Диапазон рабочих температур">-5.....+40 С</param>
        <param name="Цвет">серый</param>
        <param name="Производитель">Россия</param>
```

Вот часть моего кода:

```
i = 0
for item in spisok1: #В этом списке находятся описания товаров
    idn = item[item.find('offer id') + 10:item.find('available') - 2] #получаем id товара
    available = item[item.find('available') + 11:item.find('">')] #получаем наличие товара
    price = item[item.find('<price>') + 7:item.find('</price>')] #получаем цену товара
    slovar1['available'] = available #Записываем данные товара в словарь со свои ключом
    slovar1['price'] = price #Записываем данные товара в словарь со свои ключом

    print(idn)
    slovar0[idn] = slovar1  #Присваиваю ключу нового словаря значение id товара
                            #А значениями этого ключа будет словарь с описаниями
    print(i, slovar1, 'slovar1')
    print(i, slovar0, 'slovar0')

    i += 1
    if i>3: break

print('')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
print(slovar0)
```

Вот что я получаю на выходе:

```
122
0 {'available': 'true', 'price': '1590'} slovar1
0 {'122': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1590'}} slovar0
126
1 {'available': 'true', 'price': '2100'} slovar1
1 {'122': {'available': 'true', 'price': '2100'}, '126': {'available': 'true', 'price': '2100'}} slovar0
127
2 {'available': 'true', 'price': '4090'} slovar1
2 {'122': {'available': 'true', 'price': '4090'}, '126': {'available': 'true', 'price': '4090'}, '127': {'available': 'true', 'price': '4090'}} slovar0
130
3 {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'} slovar1
3 {'122': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'}, '126': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'}, '127': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'}, '130': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'}} slovar0

------------------------------------------------------------------
{'122': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'}, '126': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'}, '127': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'}, '130': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'}}
```

Почему `slovar1` "присваивается" не только новому ключу в `slovar0`, но и вообще всем ключам словаря `slovar0`? Почему значения всех ключей  перезаписываются?

Я же жёстко задаю ключ вот здесь `slovar0[idn] = slovar1` и на каждом шаге цикла этот ключ меняется на новый?

Как сделать, чтобы было так:

```
{'122': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'}, '126': {'available': 'true', 'price': '2100'}, '127': {'available': 'true', 'price': '4090'}, '130': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1990'}}
```

Comment: Дорогой нуб, я верю, что человек, дерзающий освоить такую сложную область, как программирование, способен разобраться с редактором текста на Stackoverflow и отформатировать свой вопрос так, чтобы его можно было прочитать без кровотечения из глаз.

Comment: Сделано, это мой первый вопрос

Comment: @ДенисАстаховский Можете, пожалуйста, привести `spisok1`, хотя бы частично. Так будет гораздо легче ответить на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я пытаюсь, но не в комментариях же его публиковать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код не работает так, как Вы задумывали, потому что в итоговый словарь `slovar0` добавляются не данные, а ссылки на временный словарь `slovar1`.

Вот проблемная строка:

```py
slovar0[idn] = slovar1
```

Вместо `slovar1` не подставляется содержимое, добавляется ссылка.

Поэтому, изменяя на следующей итерации `slovar1`, изменятся все элементы `slovar0`.

Окончательно доказать, что все элементы `slovar0` - это один и тот же объект `slovar1`, довольно легко, проверим оператором `is`:

```py
print(res['122'] is res['126'] is res['127'] is slovar1)  # True
```

---

### Другое решение

Для начала стоит спарсить информацию. Брать срезы - плохая идея. Поэтому я воспользовался `BeautifulSoup`.

Дальше всё просто. Используем `item_id` как ключ, а словарь с информацией как значение.

***Пример:***

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse(parsed_li: list) -> dict:
    res = {}
    for item in parsed_li:
        offer = item.find('offer')
        item_id = offer['id']
        item_available = offer['available']
        item_price = item.find('price').text

        res[item_id] = {
            'available': item_available,
            'price': item_price,
        }
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Инициализация списка spisok1
    parsed_li = [BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') for html in spisok1]

    res = parse(parsed_li)
    print(res)
```

***stdout:***

```py
{'122': {'available': 'true', 'price': '1590'}, '126': {'available': 'true', 'price': '2100'}, '127': {'available': 'true', 'price': '4090'}}
```

Comment: Да, это умное решение. И спасибо вам большое. Единственное что я хотел бы всё таки понять, что не так с моим пониманием словарей. Почему ключи перезаписываются последним значением

Comment: @ДенисАстаховский Потому что Вы добавляете в итоговый словарь (`slovar0`) не данные, а ссылку на временный словарь (`slovar1`). Сейчас постараюсь объяснить в ответе.

Comment: Да, я кажется понимаю, почему так. А реально создать новый объект на основе старого? Или добавляя новые словари в эту схему они всё равно в итоге будут ссылаться на самый первый объект? Моя идея получается совсем тупиковой или можно всё же как то доработать код, чтобы он работал?

Comment: `from copy import deepcopy` и присвоение в цикле: `slovar0[idn] = deepcopy(slovar1)` - должно работать. Но не стоит так делать. Прочитайте про `deepcopy`.

Comment: @ДенисАстаховский FYI ^^^

Comment: Благодарю. Уважаю профессионалов. Сейчас проясню всё что касается deepcopy

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [nomnoms12](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/339283/nomnoms12) и [Anton Abrosimov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/253345/anton-abrosimov)
- с вашей помощью я разобрался с копированием словарей в Python 3. Итак теперь я знаю три способа:

**1) Копия-ссылка - использовать нужно осторожно, может привести к запутанной логике, изменение ключа в словаре 2 автоматически означает изменение ключа и в словаре 1**

```
dict1 = {'x':'1', 'y': '5', 'z':'17'}
print('dict1=', dict1)
print('id dict1=', id(dict1))
dict2 = dict1
print('')
print('dict2=', dict2)
print('id dict2=', id(dict2))
print('')
dict2['y'] = 'zebra'
print('dict2=', dict2)
print('id dict2=', id(dict2))
print('')
print('dict1=', dict1)
print('id dict1=', id(dict1))
```

```html
dict1= {'x': '1', 'y': '5', 'z': '17'}
id dict1= 89467928

dict2= {'x': '1', 'y': '5', 'z': '17'}
id dict2= 89467928

dict2= {'x': '1', 'y': 'zebra', 'z': '17'}
id dict2= 89467928

dict1= {'x': '1', 'y': 'zebra', 'z': '17'}
id dict1= 89467928
```

**2) С помощью хитрой функции deepcopy - логику не запутает, зато может привести к сильной потере производительности и другим возможным проблемам, частое использование считается дурным тоном**

```
from copy import deepcopy
dict1 = {'x':'1', 'y': '5', 'z':'17'}
print('dict1=', dict1)
print('id dict1=', id(dict1))
dict2 = deepcopy(dict1)
print('')
print('dict2=', dict2)
print('id dict2=', id(dict2))
print('')
dict2['y'] = 'zebra'
print('dict2=', dict2)
print('id dict2=', id(dict2))
print('')
print('dict1=', dict1)
print('id dict1=', id(dict1))
```

```html
dict1= {'x': '1', 'y': '5', 'z': '17'}
id dict1= 89466200

dict2= {'x': '1', 'y': '5', 'z': '17'}
id dict2= 82229288

dict2= {'x': '1', 'y': 'zebra', 'z': '17'}
id dict2= 82229288

dict1= {'x': '1', 'y': '5', 'z': '17'}
id dict1= 89466200
```

**3) Копия с помощью распаковки, работает в python 3.5 и выше, логику не путает, про потерю производительности и возможные проблемы информации не нашёл. Не требует дополнительного модуля**

```
dict1 = {'x':'1', 'y': '5', 'z':'17'}
print('dict1=', dict1)
print('id dict1=', id(dict1))
dict2 = {**dict1}
print('')
print('dict2=', dict2)
print('id dict2=', id(dict2))
print('')
dict2['y'] = 'zebra'
print('dict2=', dict2)
print('id dict2=', id(dict2))
print('')
print('dict1=', dict1)
print('id dict1=', id(dict1))
```

```html
    dict1= {'x': '1', 'y': '5', 'z': '17'}
    id dict1= 89462104

    dict2= {'x': '1', 'y': '5', 'z': '17'}
    id dict2= 89467208

    dict2= {'x': '1', 'y': 'zebra', 'z': '17'}
    id dict2= 89467208

    dict1= {'x': '1', 'y': '5', 'z': '17'}
    id dict1= 89462104
```